# Improve setFormula('=HLOOKUP) with for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vlookup

I have a speadsheet, composed by two sheets, "Dispatcher" and another one (active one).

I would like to use a hlookup in order to look at the header C1 coming from the active sheet, find it in the "Dispatcher" sheet, copy the rows below the header from the "Dispatcher" sheet and paste it within the active one.

I tought to develop a for loop as the last row is not always the same reference within the "Dispatcher" sheet.

Below is the code I try to develop.

```
function hlookup() {
  var valuesFromDispatcherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dispatcher");
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Avals = valuesFromDispatcherSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

   for(var i=0;i<Alast;i++){
     spreadsheet.getRange(i, "column").activate();
     spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=HLOOKUP($C$1, Dispatcher!$1:$1000, i, FALSE) ');
   }
};
```

However, it seems the for loop does not work with the implementation of the "i" within the setFormula.

Do you have any idea to improve this code?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Please do not hesitate to tell me if you need further information.